# how to parse google search results on iphone

Tags: iphone, parsing, google-search

I am trying to implement a search tool on my iPhone, when i enter a text it will be send to the google for searching. and return the result.

I need to know how the text is given to the Google search engine and how the google is returning the result? Is it in the XML format or JSON.

I can then parse the result XML/JSON on my iPhone and want to display the results in my table view. Any idea? need Help...!

Thanks in advance,

Shibin

Answer (score 0):

either / or / any

One approach would be to use the google REST search API which returns JSON

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/04/google-search-rest-api.html